# Split date time, with only time, into minutes and seconds

Tags: database-design, ms-access, excel, import

I'm creating an Access database from an excel file that contains metadata about vhs tapes and DVDs. The person who created the excel file had the running times as a date/time field in minutes:seconds. I would like to be able to create reports or set up forms/queries etc. where the user can search for minutes greater than such and such. I was thinking that the best way would be to create two fields: minutes and seconds. The date/time type is really for specifying chronological times, not running times.

What is the best way to do this? How can I split the minutes:seconds to create two columns?

I only just imported the Excel table into Access. Would it be easier to do it as a formula in Excel and then import to Access?

Answer (score 1):

Store the running time as an integer in total seconds.  For display purposes you can convert the number of seconds into a string in hours:minutes:seconds format or whatever display format you choose.

Answer (score 0):

The DatePart function will extract a specified part of a date/time field.

The following example extracts the hour from the current time.

```
=DatePart("h", Now())
```

Here is a [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/extract-a-part-of-a-date-or-time-value-HP001098487.aspx) with more information on the function.

Comment: Is it appropriate to use the Date type for the running time of a video?  Seems not. Don't you think I should use a different data type?

Comment: My apologies; I misread your question. You probably shouldn't use two columns that represent the total time. The best option would be to use one column with a Double datatype where the decimal would represent the seconds. It's not ideal, but I don't know of a better way to represent time in Access.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Between the two, I think I will take your first suggestion. Using the Date data type at least has a spot for minutes and seconds, and is less likely to be confusing.